# How can I get a List of all UClasses in the project (Blueprint and C++)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I want to get a list of all UClasses.

I tried to search in ClassViewer but it gives me a SWidget so I don't know how can I get an UUserWidget* from it.

```
 FClassViewerModule& ClassViewerModule = FModuleManager::LoadModuleChecked<FClassViewerModule>("ClassViewer");
 FClassViewerInitializationOptions initClassViewer = FClassViewerInitializationOptions();
 FOnClassPicked onClassPicked = FOnClassPicked();
 TSharedRef<SWidget> classesWidget = ClassViewerModule.CreateClassViewer(initClassViewer, onClassPicked);
```

If I can't get an UUserWidget* from that SWidget then, is there another way to get a list of all UClasses that are currently created in the project?

**EDIT**

I just want to get a list of UClasses so I can put it in a widget ComboBox, I thought that if I get an UUserWidget from "classesWidget" then I could get the values of UClasses (they should be inside a PanelBox), but what I really need is to get the list, it doesn't need to be an UUserWidget, that question was because I found that method.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your exact problem is. Are you asking how to have the user select a `UUserWidget` subclass and then instantiate it at runtime? I'm not sure what `UUserWidget` has to do with getting a list of all `UClass` subclasses.

Comment: @Ruzihm I just want to get a list of UClasses so I can put it in a widget ComboBox, I thought that if I get an UUserWidget from "classesWidget" then I could get the values of UClasses (they should be inside a PanelBox), but what I really need is to get the list, it doesn't need to be an UUserWidget, that question was because I found that method.

Comment: TSubClassOf will get you an asset picker for free, there’s also a property view widget in the engine meant to replicate the same behaviour, though I forget the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally just put a TObjectIterator so I can get every class I want:

```
    for (TObjectIterator<UClass> It; It; ++It)
    {
        if (It->IsChildOf(AActor::StaticClass()) || It->IsChildOf(APawn::StaticClass()) || It->IsChildOf(ACharacter::StaticClass()))
        {
            actorClasses.Add(*It);
        }
        else if (It->IsChildOf(USceneComponent::StaticClass()))
        {
            componentClasses.Add(*It);
        }
        else if (It->IsChildOf(UUserWidget::StaticClass()))
        {
            widgets.Add(*It);
        }
    }
```